# Request chaining through nodejs not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, chaining

I have this code which makes post call

```
var request = require('request');
function makePostCall( options, callback )
{
    console.log(callback);
    request.post( options, function(error, response, body){
        if( error ) 
        {
            console.log( error );
        } 
        console.log( options.url );
        if ( callback ) { callback(); }             
    });
}
```

I am trying to use it this way

```
function call1()
{
    makePostCall( options, call2 );
}

function call2()
{
    makePostCall( options );
}
```

Control never reaches `call2` and there is only one log in the console (one that displays `callback`). I think callback handler of the post is not getting executed. Any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Here is what my option look like

```
var host = "http://localhost:3000";
var postMethod = "POST";
var options = { timeout: 1500, "url" : host + "/api/DataSource", "method" : postMethod, "body" : JSON.stringify({})};
```

Comment: Are you sure the `options` provided to request module are correct?

Comment: You're logging `callback`, does it show? Is it the function you expect? If there is only one log in the console, does that mean that `console.log( options.url );` does nothing?

Comment: @Quentin yes `console.log(callback);` shows up, but internal `console.log( options.url );` doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Does the server you are making the request to show it in its logs?

Comment: @Quentin No, the call isn't reaching the server also.

Comment: Did you try adding a timeout to your `options` (e.g. `timeout: 1500`) to see if your `request.post()` callback gets called after at most 1.5 seconds?

Comment: @mscdex I tried it now, it didn't work.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin i have attached the options, any thing I missed?

Comment: I don't think you need to stringify the `body` of the request. Do you hit your api with this request at all?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin if I do that I get `[Error: Argument error, options.body.]` from the callback handler of post.

Comment: @gurvinder372 when running your code, I see `call2` being invoked. Are you sure there isn't an issue with your API endpoint? Perhaps your second call isn't being hit due to waiting for a reply from the first?